# Calling other Class in a Class

Tags: python, class

The class `Affine` and `Sigmoid` are defined and used inside of the class `TwoLayerNet`. The `Affine` and `Sigmoid` class are static class or inner class? (It looks simple but quite strange for the beginner like me. Classes are referred using class name and the classes being called are defined outside of the class.)

```
import numpy as np


class Sigmoid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = []

    def forward(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


class Affine:
    def __init__(self, W, b):
        self.params = [W, b]

    def forward(self, x):
        W, b = self.params
        out = np.dot(x, W) + b
        return out


class TwoLayerNet:
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        I, H, O = input_size, hidden_size, output_size

        W1 = np.random.randn(I, H)
        b1 = np.random.randn(H)
        W2 = np.random.randn(H, O)
        b2 = np.random.randn(O)

        # The Affine and Sigmoid classes are called.
        # They are static classes?  or inner classes?
        self.layers = [
            Affine(W1, b1),     
            Sigmoid(),
            Affine(W2, b2)
        ]

       
        self.params = []
        for layer in self.layers:
            self.params += layer.params

    def predict(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer.forward(x)
        return x


x = np.random.randn(10, 2)
model = TwoLayerNet(2, 4, 3)
s = model.predict(x)
print(s)
```

Comment: "static class" and "inner class" refers to how classes are defined, not used. The first isn't even possible in Python, and the second doesn't apply in this code.

Comment: `self.layers = [Affine(W1, b1), Sigmoid(), Affine(W2, b2)]` _creates_ a list of 3 _unnamed_ objects.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The only explicit questions in both title and body can be answered with just "no and no". Are you aware what the terms "static class" and "inner class" actually mean?